# SQL query to get data if fields match or null if they dont

Tags: sql

I need to get a list of users with their corresponding `bed_id` in case user has `bed_id` and fill with `null` if user doesn't have `bed_id` since there will always been more users than beds.

When I try this:

```
select users.*, beds.bed_id from users, beds where users.user_id = beds.user_id;
```

I got a list of users who have assigned `bed_id` alone but I need the complete list of users with their `bed_id` or `null`.

```
USERS
--------------
| user_id    |
| name       |
| field1     |
| field2     |
| ...        |
--------------

BEDS
--------------
| bed_id     |
| user_id    |
| room_id    |
| field1     |
| ...        |
--------------
```

Thanks for the great support you always share here.

Comment: you need to use left join

Comment: Thanks for your good explanation, most questions are much less detailed. Since it was already mentioned a LEFT or even LEFT OUTER JOIN will do, I just want to say it's generally recommended to do not use comma-"JOINING" tables, but to always use JOIN, LEFT JOIN etc. If you want to know why, this is a good option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause

Comment: MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @JonasMetzler: as you're probably aware, `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` mean the same thing.

Comment: @SalmanA Hello. It is an Oracle DB. MT0s answer works as expected for now. Is there any different on doing a left outer join between MySQL and Oracle? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
select users.*,
       beds.bed_id
from   users
       LEFT OUTER JOIN beds
       ON (users.user_id = beds.user_id);
```

Comment: Thanks @MT0 and everyone who sent an answer. The left outer join is working great for me.